# Customs flag on passport

Tags: customs-and-immigration

I was looking for some advice. Recently came back from France with a couple of friends and had the usual questions. We all had cigarettes and tabacco. Over the limit granted but it was all for personal use. The customs officer pulled us in and as we where all over advised that she's put a mark on the car and out passports. We didn't like to question too much but was wondering what that actually means? I generally travel on my own for work regularly and I don't generally bring back tabacco on these trips. Does it now mean il be stopped every time or is it just the car that it will affect?

Comment: Which country are the customs agents members of?  You give the country you left, but you didnt give the country you were entering - it can be assumed the UK, but without confirmation its just a guess.

Comment: On the car?  You mean card?

Comment: Probably they were driving, so the car's license plate has been flagged in some database.

Comment: We where leaving France and entering the UK via the tunnel. And yes the car. She said she would be flagging the car

Comment: There's no strict limit for moving cigarettes and tobacco within the EU. Could you clarify what the 'mark' was and what was the origin of your cigarettes?